# Testing an async method call

Tags: java, testing, junit, integration-testing

Below is a simplified setup of my application. It has a class Foobar which calls on a facade method for fetching data. The facade then calls on a web service to actually get the data and then manipulates the data a bit and then returns it to Foobar.

Now because the web service might take a good while to run, the method call to the facade needs to be asynchronous. Hence the facade's method doesn't have a return value, but instead, the method uses a callback object. Look at the example and continue reading below.

```
public class Foobar {
    private List<DTO> dtos;

    @Autowired
    private Facade facade;

    public void refresh() {
        facade.refreshFoobar(new CallBack() {
            public void dataFetched(List<DTO> dtos) {
                setDtos(dtos);
            }

        });
    }    

    public void setDtos(List<DTO> dtos) {
        this.dtos = dtos;
    }
}


public class Facade {

    ...

    public void refreshFoorbar(CallBack cb) {
        // Fetch data from a web service
        List<DTO> dtos = webService.getData();  
        // Manipulate DTOs
        ....
        // call on the callback method
        cb.dataFecthed(dtos);
    }

}
```

I have two ways of making the facade's method asynchronous, either by creating a thread manually or by using springs @Async annotation.

```
public class Facade {

    public void refreshFoorbar(CallBack cb) {
        new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ....
            }

        }.start();

    }
}

// ... OR ...

public class Facade {

    @Async
    public void refreshFoorbar(CallBack cb) {
        ....    
    }
}
```

My problem is that I now need to write an integration test for this chain of method calls. I think I need to force the async facade call to be synchronous when the integration test is ran, otherwise I won't know for sure when I can do the appropriate asserts. The only idea for making the method call synchronous is to use manually handled threads AND making the threading conditional (so, for testing purposes, I have an if clause which determines if the facade method should be ran in a separate thread or not).

However, I have a feeling that there could be a better solution to my problem, whether it be a better way of forcing the method to me synchronous, eg with spring, or by testing the multithreading on some way.

This is where I need your suggestions, how would you solve my problem? Note, I'm using junit for both unit and integration tests.

Comment: I do not know if it is the correct way. Usually testing for asynchronous conditions is just launching the asynchronous task, wait for a while and test if the task has been completed.

Answer (score 12):

Simple solution would be to return a Future object like this,

```
@Async
public Future<String> refreshFoorbar(CallBack cb) {
    yourHeavyLifting(); //asynchronous call
    return new AsyncResult<String>("yourJobNameMaybe");   
}
```

And in your test, take the future reference and call the [get()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get%28%29) method.

```
future.get(); // if its not already complete, waits for it to complete
assertTrue(yourTestCondition)
```

This [blog post](http://blog.espenberntsen.net/2010/03/08/spring-asynchronous-support/) shows a sample.

Comment: see this if it helps http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSCKBL_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tejb_clientcode.html

Answer (score 6):

When JUnit testing stuff like this, I use a testing callback with a [`CountDownLatch`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) that gets counted down by the callback and `await()`ed by the test method.

```
private static class TestingCallback implements Callback {
    private final CountDownLatch latch;
    public TestingCallback(CountDownLatch latch) {
        this.latch = latch;
    }
    @Override public void onEvent() {
        this.latch.countDown();
    }
}

@Test
public void testCallback() {
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    classUnderTest.execute( new TestCallback(latch) );

    assertTrue(latch.await(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
}
```

If the callback is invoked (asynchronously) by the code under test, the latch returns `true` and the test passes. If the callback doesn't get invoked, the test times out after thirty seconds and the assertion fails.